# Issue with Google Play games API

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I'm learning how to implement the Google Play games API and I can sign in and out without problem, but now I want to create a basic turn based game and I'm having a problem and I don't know why.

That's the problem:

[image]

Is the same code that Google says on its tutorial: [google turn based multiplayer](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/blob/master/TBMP.md)

Comment: The code and error would be more readable if you pasted them as text instead of an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `static` key word from your `CreateWithInvitationScreen` function and your problem should be gone. So, `public static void CreateWithInvitationScreen` should be changed to `public void CreateWithInvitationScreen`.

Comment: ok, that solved the problem... I'm feeling so stupid lol. Thanks you!